returning the sums of the withdraws in bank accounts
I'm working on an exercise where I'm only allowed to use 'for-loops' for iterating through the material given. in this case bank accounts and return the sums of the widrawals in a new array, but if the account lacks withdrawals then have it return '0'
I've figured out how to return the sums of the bank accounts with withdraws I'm struggling trying to figure out how to return '0' for the accounts with not withdraws the desired output should look like this
([300.68,0,5900,0,100]) but my function keeps returning this ([300.68,,5900,,100])
how can I make sure that any account without a "withdrawal" returns a 0?
this is what I Have so far
const bankAccounts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Susan",
    balance: 100.32,
    deposits: [150, 30, 221],
    withdrawals: [110, 70.68, 120],
  },
  { id: 2, name: "Morgan", balance: 1100.0, deposits: [1100] },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Joshua",
    balance: 18456.57,
    deposits: [4000, 5000, 6000, 9200, 256.57],
    withdrawals: [1500, 1400, 1500, 1500],
  },
  { id: 4, name: "Candy", balance: 0.0 },
  { id: 5, name: "Phil", balance: 18, deposits: [100, 18], withdrawals: [100] },
];



function itsSomething(array){
  let newArray = [];
  let total = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  let numbs = array[i].withdrawals
   newArray.push(numbs||0 )
   let sum =0
   for (let x =0; x < newArray[i].length; x++){
  sum+=newArray[i][x]
  total[i]= sum
   
 }
 }



  return total
}


console.log(itsSomething(bankAccounts))



In your code stems from how you're handling accounts that lack withdrawals. If a bank account has no withdrawals, your current approach still tries to push an empty array into newArray, which leads to the output you described.
Here’s how you can modify your function to ensure that it correctly returns 0 for accounts without any withdrawals:
Check if withdrawals exist before attempting to sum them up.
If the account has no withdrawals, directly push 0 to the total array.


const bankAccounts = [  
  {  
    id: 1,  
    name: "Susan",  
    balance: 100.32,  
    deposits: [150, 30, 221],  
    withdrawals: [110, 70.68, 120],  
  },  
  { id: 2, name: "Morgan", balance: 1100.0, deposits: [1100] },  
  {  
    id: 3,  
    name: "Joshua",  
    balance: 18456.57,  
    deposits: [4000, 5000, 6000, 9200, 256.57],  
    withdrawals: [1500, 1400, 1500, 1500],  
  },  
  { id: 4, name: "Candy", balance: 0.0 },  
  { id: 5, name: "Phil", balance: 18, deposits: [100, 18], withdrawals: [100] },  
];  

function itsSomething(array) {  
  let total = [];  

  
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {  
    let numbs = array[i].withdrawals; 
    let sum = 0; 

   
    if (numbs && numbs.length > 0) {  
      
      for (let x = 0; x < numbs.length; x++) {  
        sum += numbs[x];  
      }  
    } else {  
        
      sum = 0;  
    }  

    
    total.push(sum);  
  }  

  return total; 
}  

console.log(itsSomething(bankAccounts)); // Output: [300.68, 0, 5900, 0, 100]



